# How can I save a numpy.ndarray as an image in cv2 or PIL with correct MIME type and sRGB color profile?

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to save a `numpy.ndarray` as an image. It seems to work, but when I go to "Open image in a new tab" in Chrome, Chrome downloads the image instead of displaying it in a new tab.

My searches initially led me to believe that it's a MIME type issue, however all the inspectors I've looked at say that it has the MIME type of `image/jpeg`. Maybe that's just being inferred from the file extension though - I don't know how to check.

I've tried using both cv2 and PIL, with the same results.

```
Image.fromarray(img).save('/output.jpg', quality=95) # PIL
cv2.imwrite('/output.jpg', img) # cv2
```

I can also tell from the metadata inspectors that the image has no color profile. I can see that PIL has an option to set the profile in the `image.save()` method, but all the examples I can find get the profile from the original image. E.g.

```
im.save(filename, 'jpeg', icc_profile=im.info.get('icc_profile'))
```

In my case I'm building from an array so I have nowhere to get the profile from.

Comment: The MIME type isn't encoded in the file itself, it's metadata that is transmitted along with the file. If you're accessing the file directly you don't have that metadata.

Comment: You can add profiles with Python Wand. See http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.5.7/wand/image.html and search for "profile" for documentation. It will also convert numpy arrays to whatever output image format you want. However, to use it, you will need Imagemagick installed. But it comes with most Linux systems and is available for Mac OSX and Windows.